# Azure SQL database TransparentDataEncryptionProtector InternalServerError: An unexpected error occured while processing the request

Tags: sql, database, azure, encryption

I am trying to configure transparent data encryption for my Azure SQL databases using the steps documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/transparent-data-encryption-byok-azure-sql-configure
The command `Set-AzSqlServerTransparentDataEncryptionProtector` in step 3 is trowing me an error

> InternalServerError: An unexpected error occured while processing the
>   request. Tracking ID: '8decc6a3-b1e5-4860-acc6-37b1114bcc33'.

When I look in the Azure portal at the Activity Log I see the same error "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state `Failed`.

> "statusMessage":
>   "{\"status\":\"Failed\",\"error\":{\"code\":\"ResourceOperationFailure\",\"message\":\"The
>   resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state
>   'Failed'.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"InternalServerError\",\"message\":\"An
>   unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID:
>   '82fbc867-e16a-4681-96af-d410400e97f9'\"}]}}"

Anybody any idea how to trace what goes wrong?

Comment: Did you find a way to trace the issue in the end?